# PyQt5, текст из *.txt файла не загружается в QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Программа должна выводить текст из обычного `.txt` документа (кодировка - utf-8) в текстовое поле `QTextEdit`.

Программа аварийно завершается без сообщения об ошибке. Как нужно исправить код? И объясните причину ошибки, если она будет не очевидна.
Спасибо.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QFileDialog, QTextEdit

prg = QApplication(sys.argv)

tex_pole = QTextEdit()

def load():
    path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(parent=None, caption='Обрати файл', filter='text *.txt')[0]
    fil = open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    txt = fil.readlines()
    tex_pole.setText(txt)

window = QWidget()
vbx = QVBoxLayout()
hbx_zavant_zbereh_knp = QHBoxLayout()
knp_zavant_text = QPushButton('Загрузить текст')
knp_zavant_text.clicked.connect(load)
hbx_zavant_zbereh_knp.addWidget(knp_zavant_text)
vbx.addLayout(hbx_zavant_zbereh_knp)
vbx.addWidget(tex_pole)
window.setLayout(vbx)

window.show()

sys.exit(prg.exec())
```

Comment: Откуда тут open? Несколько я помню надо его из os брать. import os и далее os.open(...

Comment: Open - это обычное открытие файла. Встроенная функция.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

причина очевидна:

```
tex_pole.setText(txt)
```

> TypeError: setText(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'

Всегда запускайте свое приложение в терминале/CMD и вы получите понятную ошибку.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, \
    QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QFileDialog, QTextEdit


prg = QApplication(sys.argv)

tex_pole = QTextEdit()

def load():
    path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(parent=None, caption='Обрати файл', filter='text *.txt')[0]
    fil = open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    txt = fil.read()                            # - readlines()  + read
    tex_pole.setText(txt)

window = QWidget()
vbx = QVBoxLayout()
hbx_zavant_zbereh_knp = QHBoxLayout()
knp_zavant_text = QPushButton('Загрузить текст')
knp_zavant_text.clicked.connect(load)
hbx_zavant_zbereh_knp.addWidget(knp_zavant_text)
vbx.addLayout(hbx_zavant_zbereh_knp)
vbx.addWidget(tex_pole)
window.setLayout(vbx)

window.show()

sys.exit(prg.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, там к моей ошибке еще добавился баг IDE, после перезагрузки уже начал сообщать об ошибке.

Comment: @arachnoden пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, `readlines()` возвращает `List[]`, а `setText()` - принимает строку `str` в качестве аргумента.
Самый простой вариант, чтобы было понятно где причина:

```
def load():
    path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(parent=None, caption='Обрати файл', filter='text *.txt')[0]
    fil = open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    txt = str(fil.readlines())
    tex_pole.setText(txt)
```